# Can't read properties in a JSON object in JS

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

I've been trying to work on this project to get better at coding for about half and a month now and I've come across a problem where JSON doesn't really behave the way I want it to. When I try reading a part of a JSON object, it almost always shows 'undefined' as a result.

This is the code, where I store my JSON into a cookie:

```
var basket = '{ "basket":['+'{ "id": 0, "data-id": 3, "amount": 1  }'+'] }';
                document.cookie = 'basket='+JSON.parse(basket)+'; max-age="604800"; path=/';
```

I read it with:

```
var basket = getCookie('basket');

                    for(var i in basket) {
                        alert(basket[i]);
                    }
```

This is the last approach I've tried, this one returns the '{' (i.e. the first character of the JSON when I define it), meaning it behaves as if it were a string, right? In cases, where I've tried to read it with just alert(basket[0]) or alert(basket.basket[0].id) or anything (I've tried countless combinations) it almost always returns 'undefined' with the exception of only returning a part of a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `basket` variable contains JSON, but the you turn in back into an object with `JSON.parse()`. Why? Do you need the JSON on the server side? Does `getCookie()` parse the JSON back to an object again?

Answer (score 0):

Declare basket object and while saving into cookie use `JSON.stringify()` method to save it; and when you extract it from cookie use `JSON.parse()` method to convert it back from string to object.

```
let basket = {basket:[{id: 0, dataId: 3, amount: 1  }] };
document.cookie = 'basket='+JSON.stringify(basket)+'; max-age="604800"; path=/';

function getBasketFromCookie() {
    const basketValue = document.cookie
        .split('; ')
        .find(row => row.startsWith('basket='))
        .split('=')[1];

    const basketObj = JSON.parse(basketValue);
    return basketObj;
}

const basketObj = getBasketFromCookie();
// print basket object
for (let key in basketObj) {
    console.log(basket[key]);
}
```

> console output:

[image]